# Displaying Neo4j with d3.js

Tags: d3.js, neo4j

I following this tutorial (http://blog.ashokalella.com/neo4j/d3/2015/04/27/neo4j-and-d3/).

How can I add name on the graph?

Like this (http://bl.ocks.org/mbostock/1153292).

Please help me.

Thank you.

Comment: Instead of using d3, which is a rather low level library, you might benefit from using a high level data viz lib like [vis.js](http://visjs.org/network_examples.html) which provides a higher level API for building network visualizations.

Comment: They've moved the examples to here: https://visjs.github.io/vis-network/examples/

Answer (score 3):

Here is a detailed how-to on data visualization:

http://neo4j.com/developer/guide-data-visualization/

In d3 you would then add another function to return the label/caption of the node accessing the node itself like shown in the blocks:

```
var text = svg.append("g").selectAll("text")
    .data(force.nodes())
  .enter().append("text")
    .attr("x", 8)
    .attr("y", ".31em")
    .text(function(d) { return d.name; });
```

Comment: Sorry,I don't know how add name.